# jQuery: checking slideToggle visibility not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use slide toggle to show a sign in form and if they click outside of the box, I want that form to slide up.

I have everything running fine however my check for visibility isn't working and thus clicking outside the form container is not working.  Can you spot why?

```
var loginForm = jQuery("#login .login-form");
jQuery("#login a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginForm.slideToggle();

});

// below check isn't working why?
if (jQuery(loginForm).is(":visible")) {
    jQuery("body").click(function() {
        jQuery(loginForm).slideUp();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why no one uses the `$` today? People started like writing or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the check inside the click handler:

```
jQuery("body").click(function() {
    if (loginForm.is(":visible")) {
        loginForm.slideUp();
    }
});
```

An additional note, you don't need to call `jQuery` on an object which is already a jQuery object.  No need to double wrap your `loginForm`.

You will want to `event.stopPropagation()` in your login click handler as well, otherwise clicking on it will bubble up to the body and fire that handler as well.

Comment: Can you please explain why if (loginForm.is(":visible")) { alert('yes'); } won't work?

Comment: Your `if` is outside of the `click` handler.  What your code does is on load of the page, checks if your form is visible and if so, then it attaches the handler.  If your form is not visible on initial load the handler is not attached at all.

Comment: Ok so if I made the form initially visibility:hidden instead of display:none, then my code would work.  Is your solution the only way to go about?  The reason why I ask is it would seem every click on the page would test if the form is visible even if the form was not visible instead of first checking if the form is visible and then apply the function.  thx.

Comment: If you made the form visible your code would `slideUp` on every click of the body.  If you wanted to, you could place the `body.click` within your other click handler, and unbind the `body.click` once it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code being executed from? Are you sure that the `document` is ready when you are binding the `click` handler?

Also, the `loginForm` variable is already wrapped in `jQuery`, no need to do it again:

```
// Make sure the document is ready for manipulating the DOM:
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    var loginForm = $( '#login .login-form' );

    $( '#login a' ).click( function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.slideToggle();    
    });

    if ( loginForm.is( ':visible' ) ) {
        $( document ).click( function () {
            loginForm.slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```